# If a sports team is down by 1-2 in a best of 7 series, what is their chance of winning (if both teams have a 1/2 chance of winning every game)?

Tags: probability

I know that the team has to win 3 of the 4 remaining games. So I thought that from the 4 remaining games, there are a total of $2^4 = 16$ total different outcomes.

Could someone point me towards the right direction to determine the probability of the team winning 3 of the 4 remaining games? Would it be 4C3/16 since the three wins can be chosen amongst the 4 games left?

Comment: The winning scenarios are $WWW, WWLW, WLWW, LWWW$ so...  If it helps, you can think of $WWW$ as short hand for the two scenarios $WWWW$ and $WWWL$.

Comment: You can draw a tree diagram, if you're familiar with that.

Comment: Note:  your thought, $\binom 43\times \frac 1{16}$, is close but not correct since your team might win the next three (in which case there is no "missing" slot).

Comment: Drawing a tree diagram helped me, but is there a way to approach this problem without a diagram? I'm having difficulty excluding the probabilities that is impossible to occur, such as the team winning all of the remaining four games.

Comment: Either the series ends in exactly $2$ more games, or $3$ more games, or $4$ more games.  For each case, calculate the probability each team wins in exactly that number of additional games.  Then sum these probabilities for the given team.

Comment: You just need to add the probability of winning 4 games in a row since that is considered winning. Doesn't matter if in reality they don't play that 4th game or not. Think about it, is there any difference between winning and not winning the series if they play that last game? There is a reason why we don't play that last game sometimes.

Comment: MatthewLiu:  You do *not* need to "add the probability of winning $4$ games in a row" because once the behind team wins $3$ games (no matter the order), the additional game will never be played—same as with the other terminating sequences.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork When I try breaking it down into cases, I keep on getting a different answer from the tree diagram I drew. Could you give me one example without writing out all the cases (or drawing a tree diagram)?

Answer (score 2):

The team that's behind needs to win three of the remaining four games.

One possibility is to explicitly write out all the possible scenarios: WWW, WWLW, WLWW, LWWW.  These have probability 1/8, 1/16, 1/16, and 1/16, so the probability of winning is the sum of these, 5/16.

Alternatively, imagine that all four remaining games get played even if they don't need to be.  Then the probability that the team that's behind wins at least three of its games is just the probability that a binomial(4, 1/2) random variable is at least 3 - that's

$$ {{4 \choose 3} + {4 \choose 4} \over 2^4} = {4 + 1 \over 16} = {5 \over 16}$$

Comment: for your second method, aren't you double counting some scenarios, such as WWW and WWWW?

Comment: with a tree diagram, the probability I got is 2/5. The list of scenarios are: WWW, WWLW, WWLL, WLWW, WLWL, WLL, LWWW, LWWL, LWL, LL, where the team wins on 4/10 of those.

Comment: @TimWeah In the second method, WWW doesn't appear, because they are looking at 4-game combinations, and that's only three games. For your calculation of probabilities, are you weighting each scenario by the probability of seeing that scenario?

Comment: @Acccumulation I just used a tree diagram (like the one below), and got 2/5. I'm just trying to figure out a way to show my solution numerically, but am having difficulty.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with a reply to the OP's request for a tree:

[image]

Calculate the probabilities of getting to a "winning" end $42$ and $43$, being sure to add the probabilities along all paths:

$\underbrace{(1/2)^3}_{{\rm path~to~} 42} + \underbrace{3 (1/2)^4}_{{\rm paths~to~} 43} = 5/16$

Comment: Thats exactly what I have, but (since a tree diagram is not sufficient enough for this course), I'm trying to figure out a way to show this numerically. (not sure if thats the correct term)

Answer (score 1):

Let $p(a,b)$ be the probability that team A is the first to win 4 games, given that team A has already won $a$ games and team B has already won $b$ games. By conditioning on the outcome of the next game, we see that $p$ satisfies the following recurrence relations:
\begin{align}
p(4,b) &= 1 \\
p(a,4) &= 0 \\
p(a,b) &= \frac{1}{2} p(a+1,b) + \frac{1}{2} p(a,b+1) &&\text{if $a<4$ and $b<4$}
\end{align}
You want to compute $p(1,2)$.  Now
\begin{align}
p(1,2)&=\frac{1}{2} p(2,2) + \frac{1}{2} p(1,3)\\
&=\frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} p(3,2) + \frac{1}{2} p(2,3)\right) 
+ \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} p(2,3) + \frac{1}{2} p(1,4)\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{4} p(3,2) + \frac{1}{2} p(2,3) + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 0\\
&=\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{2} p(4,2) + \frac{1}{2} p(3,3)\right) + \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{2} p(3,3) + \frac{1}{2} p(2,4)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{8} \cdot 1 + \frac{3}{8} p(3,3) + \frac{1}{4} \cdot 0 \\
&=\frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{8} \left(\frac{1}{2} p(4,3) + \frac{1}{2} p(3,4)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{8} \left(\frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{8} + \frac{3}{16} \\
&=\frac{5}{16}
\end{align}